# Object ArrayList attributes

Tags: java, variables, object, arraylist, attributes

For instance i have an arraylist of objects. It is a student object with these attributes

```
public Student(String name, String address)
{
  if (name == null)
     name = "";
  if (address == null)
     address = "";
  this.name = name;
  this.address = address;
  lastAssignedNumber++;//Starts at 1000
  studentNum = lastAssignedNumber;
  // at first no credits have been taken (so no grade points either)
  totalCredits = 0;
  totalPoints = 0.0;
```

}

Say i have added multiple objects into this arraylist. I want to edit A object in the arraylist based on the studentNum.

Lets call the arraylist mylist:

I know that mylist.get(studentNum) won't work because it gets the index of the list. Is there a way to get edit a certain object base on the studentNum?

Comment: you can use `Map` of `studentId` vs `Student` ?

Comment: I think i wasn't specific enough. SO i find the studentNum in the arraylist then based on the studentNum i wana edit that object so the totalcredit gets changed(i think i know how to do this but i can't locate the object in the array)

Answer (score 0):

The best match for your requirement is to use a Map interface with any Concrete implementation.

Then the key value pair will be `Id` as `Long` ,and `Student` object as `value`.

```
Map<Long,Student> students= new HashMap<Long,Student>();
```

Then you can use it as

```
students.put(stu.getId(), student);
```

getting

```
  Student st=  students.get(stu.getId());
```

***Otherwise you end up with iteration each time***

Comment: @sanbhat Ahh.. Thanks. That's a blunder.

Answer (score 0):

Say I was looking for a student with studentNum of 32

```
for(Student s : mylist) {
  if(32 == s.getStudentNum) {
    theStudent = s;
  }
}
```

This is assuming the above data structure, if you wanted to create a map with studentNum as the key and the student object as the value, that'd be much more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Map:

```
Map<Integer, Student> students = new HashMap<>();
```

put student and id:

```
students.put(studentNum, student);
```

and get the student by id:

```
students.get(studentNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `Student` object ***overrides*** `equals` considering `studentNumber` field, then you can get the `Student` by doing find by example

First create an example

```
Student example = new Student();
s.setStudentNum(32); //If you want to find student with id 32
```

then you can do find by example

```
Student toFind = arrayList.get(arrayList.indexOf(example));
```